# Copy all pictures from a folder and insert them as renamed into another folder. Source path and destination path stored in database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I would like to create a python script which loops trough all the pictures in a folder and copy and paste renamed them into another folder. the relative source destination path with filename stored in database in table1, column1 and the destination path with file name stored in the same table in column2. I am not sure where to start, I guess I need write a select query based on the picture `relativepath/filename` and if there is a match in table1 then execute copy and rename to `relativepath2/newfilename`, where this was used from the matched row. Not sure where to start, I am ok with SQL, but limited with Python.

Comment: There are plenty of answers to this is in SO. Search on *Python rename files* to begin with.